# Softlayer script for retrieving graphs for specific metrics for a single server is not working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The Softlayer gist script "[softlayer/monitoringGraph.php](https://gist.github.com/softlayer/834081)" is not working for us.

We are getting this error message:

> Unable to retrieve graph image: There was an error querying the
>   SoftLayer API: The configuration value supplied is invalid.

Debugging the script shows that `$cdmConfigurationValues` is empty.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The script works fine, I think the server for which you want to retrieve graphs doesn't have a monitoring agent, that's the issue that you have, you need to add a monitoring package to the server. You can verify the monitoring configurations from your servers in the following link:

https://control.softlayer.com/devices/monitoring